# Deciphering sed commands

Tags: sed

I just run across the following `sed` command:

```
sed "s|^/samba|\\|;s|/|\\|g"
```

I have seen `sed` substitute commands before. I also know sed allows the usage of any character as a delimeter (`|` in this case) and that `g` means global substitution.

However, I am not sure what the rest of the command does.

Perhaps more generally, how can I **quickly** find information on what a `sed` pattern like the one above does? (other than obviously reading the documentation, which is always recommended)

Comment: try `print -r '/nfs/x/y' | sed 's|^/nfs|\\|;s|/|\\|g'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's TWO sed commands, separated by a semicolon. The first replaced /nfs at the beginning of the line with \, the second replaces any / with \ :)

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I just updated the OP with an error that I get